# Prove: $\sum\limits_{cyc} \sqrt{9a^2+(a+b+c)^2} \ge \sqrt{12(a^2+b^2+c^2)+14(a+b+c)^2}$ with $a,b,c>0.$

Tags: inequality, sum-of-squares-method, triangle-inequality

> Let $a,b,c>0.$ Prove that $$ \sqrt{9a^2+(a+b+c)^2}+\sqrt{9b^2+(a+b+c)^2}+\sqrt{9c^2+(a+b+c)^2} \ge \sqrt{12(a^2+b^2+c^2)+14(a+b+c)^2}$$

I see it on Facebook [here](https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=2923662311102980&set=gm.3524240534530649&idorvanity=1486244404996949).
I tried Mincopxki, but it doesn't help.
$$\sum\limits_{cyc} \sqrt{9a^2+(a+b+c)^2} \ge \sqrt{9(a+b+c)^2+9(a+b+c)^2}=\sqrt{18}(a+b+c).$$
But the following $a^2+b^2+c^2 \le ab+bc+ca$ is not true.

I think it's very hard, I also tried AM-GM, Cauchy - Schwarz, but it is not word too.
Please help me, thank all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $a+b+c=3$ and $a\geq b\geq c$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$3\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a^2+1}\geq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}(26a^2+28ab)}$$ or
$$9\sum_{cyc}\left(a^2+1+2\sqrt{(a^2+1)(b^2+1)}\right)\geq\sum_{cyc}(26a^2+28ab)$$ or
$$18\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(a^2+1)(b^2+1)}\geq\sum_{cyc}(26a^2+28ab-9a^2-3a^2-6ab)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(-14a^2-22ab+9(a^2+1+b^2+1))\geq9\sum_{cyc}\left(a^2+1-2\sqrt{(a^2+1)(b^2+1)}+b^2+1\right)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(4a^2-22ab+6a^2+12ab)\geq9\sum_{cyc}\left(\sqrt{a^2+1}-\sqrt{b^2+1}\right)^2$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(10a^2-10ab)\geq9\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a^2-b^2)^2}{\left(\sqrt{a^2+1}+\sqrt{b^2+1}\right)^2}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2\left(5-\frac{9(a+b)^2}{\left(\sqrt{a^2+1}+\sqrt{b^2+1}\right)^2}\right)\geq0.$$
Now, by Minkowski(triangle inequality): $$5-\frac{9(b+c)^2}{\left(\sqrt{b^2+1}+\sqrt{c^2+1}\right)^2}\geq5-\frac{9(b+c)^2}{(b+c)^2+4}=\frac{20-4(b+c)^2}{(b+c)^2+4}\geq\frac{20-4\cdot2^2}{(b+c)^2+4}>0.$$
Also, by Minkowski again  $$5-\frac{9(a+c)^2}{\left(\sqrt{a^2+1}+\sqrt{c^2+1}\right)^2}=5-\frac{9(a+c)^2}{\left(\sqrt{a^2+1}+\sqrt{1+c^2}\right)^2}\geq$$
$$\geq5-\frac{9(a+c)^2}{(a+1)^2+(c+1)^2}=\frac{2(5a+5c+5-2a^2-9ac-2c^2)}{(a+1)^2+(c+1)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{2(15(a+c)(a+b+c)+5(a+b+c)^2-9(2a^2+9ac+2c^2))}{9((a+1)^2+(c+1)^2)}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{2(15(a+c)(a+2c)+5(a+2c)^2-9(2a^2+9ac+2c^2))}{9((a+1)^2+(c+1)^2)}=\frac{4(a-4c)^2}{9((a+1)^2+(c+1)^2)}\geq0.$$
Thus, by Minkowski again we obtain: $$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2\left(5-\frac{9(a+b)^2}{\left(\sqrt{a^2+1}+\sqrt{b^2+1}\right)^2}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq(a-b)^2\left(5-\frac{9(a+b)^2}{\left(\sqrt{a^2+1}+\sqrt{b^2+1}\right)^2}\right)+(a-c)^2\left(5-\frac{9(a+c)^2}{\left(\sqrt{a^2+1}+\sqrt{c^2+1}\right)^2}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq(a-b)^2\left(5-\frac{9(a+b)^2}{\left(\sqrt{a^2+1}+\sqrt{b^2+1}\right)^2}\right)+(a-b)^2\left(5-\frac{9(a+c)^2}{\left(\sqrt{a^2+1}+\sqrt{c^2+1}\right)^2}\right)=$$
$$=(a-b)^2\left(10-\frac{9(a+b)^2}{\left(\sqrt{a^2+1}+\sqrt{b^2+1}\right)^2}-\frac{9(a+c)^2}{\left(\sqrt{a^2+1}+\sqrt{c^2+1}\right)^2}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq(a-b)^2\left(10-\frac{9(a+b)^2}{(a+1)^2+(b+1)^2}-\frac{9(a+c)^2}{(a+1)^2+(c+1)^2}\right)$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$10-\frac{9(a+b)^2}{\left(a+\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^2+\left(b+\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^2}-\frac{9(a+c)^2}{\left(a+\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^2+\left(c+\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^2}\geq0$$ or
$$68a^4-220(b+c)a^3+(147b^2+78bc+147c^2)a^2+(b+c)(443b^2-518bc+443c^2)a+$$
$$+89b^4+545b^3c+588b^2c^2+545bc^3+89c^4\geq0$$ or
$$68a^4-220(b+c)a^3+(147(b+c)^2-216bc)a^2+(b+c)(443(b+c)^2-1404bc)a+$$
$$+89(b+c)^4+27bc(7(b+c)^2-10bc)\geq0.$$
Now, let $b+c=constant$ and $bc=x$.

Thus, we need to prove that $f(x)\geq0,$ where
$$f(x)=68a^4-220(b+c)a^3+(147(b+c)^2-216x)a^2+(b+c)(443(b+c)^2-1404x)a+$$
$$+89(b+c)^4+27x(7(b+c)^2-10x).$$
But $$f'(x)=-216a^2-1404(b+c)a+189(b+c)^2-540x<0,$$ which says that it's enough to prove $f(x)\geq0$ for a maximal value of $x$, which happens for $b=c$.

Now, let $b=c=1$.

Thus, it remains to prove that:
$$68a^4-440a^3+372a^2+736a+1856\geq0$$ or
$$(a-4)^2(17a^2+26a+29)\geq0$$ and we are done.

Comment: Very nice SOS. Thanks @Michale Rozenberg.

Comment: @Nguyễn Thái An  You are welcome

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice proof.

Due to homogeneity, let $a+b+c=3$.
The inequality becomes:
\begin{align*} \sqrt{a^2+1}+\sqrt{b^2+1}+\sqrt{c^2+1} \ge \sqrt{\frac{4}{3}\left(a^2+b^2+c^2 \right)+14} \end{align*}
Squaring both sizes gives:
\begin{align*} \sum_{\text{cyc}}{\sqrt{\left(a^2+1 \right) \left(b^2+1 \right)}} \ge \frac{1}{6} \left(a^2+b^2+c^2 \right) +\frac{11}{2}\end{align*}
or,
\begin{align*} \sum_{\text{cyc}} \left[ \sqrt{\left(a^2+1 \right) \left(b^2+1 \right)} -a-b\right] \ge \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2 -3}{6}\end{align*}
or,
\begin{align*} \sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{\left(ab-1 \right)^2}{\sqrt{\left(a^2+1 \right) \left(b^2+1 \right)}+a+b}\ge \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2 -3}{6}\end{align*}
Applying AM-GM inequality:
\begin{align*} \sqrt{\left(a^2+1 \right) \left(b^2+1 \right)} +a+b &\le \frac{a^2+b^2+2}{2} +a+b \\ &= \frac{\left(a+1 \right)^2 + \left(b+1 \right)^2}{2}\end{align*}
It suffices to prove that:
\begin{align*} \sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{\left(ab-1 \right)^2}{\left(a+1 \right)^2 + \left(b+1 \right)^2} \ge \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2-3}{12}\end{align*}
WLOG, assume $a\ge b \ge c$ then $a \ge 1$. Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have:
\begin{align*} \frac{\left(ab-1 \right)^2}{\left(a+1 \right)^2 + \left(b+1 \right)^2} + \frac{\left(ca-1 \right)^2}{\left(c+1 \right)^2 + \left(a+1 \right)^2} & \ge \frac{\left(ab-ca \right)^2}{2 \left(a+1 \right)^2 + \left(b+1 \right)^2 + \left(c+1 \right)^2} \\ & \ge \frac{\left(ab-ca \right)^2}{2 \left(a+a \right)^2 + \left(a+a \right)^2 + \left(a+a \right)^2} \\ & = \frac{1}{16} \left(b-c \right)^2\end{align*}
Also, it is easy to see that:
\begin{align*} \frac{\left(bc-1 \right)^2}{\left(b+1 \right)^2 + \left(c+1 \right)^2} \ge \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{b+c}{2} - 1\right)^2 \Longleftrightarrow \left( b-c\right)^2 \left( b^2+4bc+c^2-2b-2c-2\right) \le 0\end{align*}
Which is true because:
\begin{align} \left(b^2+2bc+c^2\right) + 2bc \le \left(b+c\right)^2 + \frac{\left(b+c\right)^2}{2} \le 2 \left(b+c \right) + 2 \end{align}
where $b+c \le 2$.

Thus,
\begin{align} \sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{\left(ab-1 \right)^2}{\left(a+1 \right)^2 + \left(b+1 \right)^2} & \ge \frac{1}{16}\left(b-c \right)^2 + \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{b+c}{2} - 1 \right)^2 \\ & = \frac{1}{16}\left(b-c \right)^2 +\frac{1}{72} \left(b+c-2a \right)^2 \\ & \ge \frac{1}{24} \left(b-c\right)^2 + \frac{1}{72} \left(b+c-2a \right)^2  = \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2-3}{12}\end{align}
We have Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

We need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{10a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+ac+bc)}\geq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}(26a^2+28abc)}.$$

Let $a\geq b\geq c$.

Thus,
$$\sqrt{a^2+10b^2+c^2+2(ab+ac+bc)}+\sqrt{a^2+b^2+10c^2+2(ab+ac+bc)}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{4a^2+17.5b^2+17.5c^2+8ab+8ac+17bc}$$ it's
$$4\sqrt{(a^2+10b^2+c^2+2(ab+ac+bc))(a^2+b^2+10c^2+2(ab+ac+bc)}\geq$$
$$\geq4a^2+13b^2+13c^2+8ab+8ac+26bc$$ or
$$(b-c)^2(8a^2+16ab+16ac-b^2-38bc-c^2)\geq0,$$ which is true for $a\geq b\geq c$.

Thus, it remains to prove that:

$$\sqrt{4a^2+17.5b^2+17.5c^2+8ab+8ac+17bc}+\sqrt{10a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+ac+bc)}\geq$$$$\geq\sqrt{\sum\limits_{cyc}(26a^2+28bc)}$$ or
$$8(8a^2+35b^2+35c^2+16ab+16ac+34bc)(10a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+ac+bc))\geq$$$$\geq9(8a^2+5b^2+5c^2+12ab+12ac+6bc)^2$$ or
$$64a^4-320(b+c)a^3+48(23b^2-2bc+23c^2)a^2-8(b+c)(49b^2+62bc+49c^2)a+$$
$$+55b^4+292b^3c+330b^2c^2+292bc^3+55c^4\geq0$$ or
$$64a^4-320(b+c)a^3+48(23(b+c)^2-48bc)a^2-8(b+c)(49(b+c)^2-36bc)a+$$
$$+55(b+c)^4+72bc((b+c)^2-2bc).$$
Now, let $b+c=constant$ and $bc=x$.

Thus, we need to prove that $f(x)\geq0,$ where
$$f(x)=64a^4-320(b+c)a^3+48(23(b+c)^2-48x)a^2-8(b+c)(49(b+c)^2-36x)a+$$
$$+55(b+c)^4+72x((b+c)^2-2x).$$
But $$f'(x)=-48^2a^2+288(b+c)a+72(b+c)^2-288x=$$
$$=72(-32a^2+4(b+c)a+(b+c)^2-4bc)\leq$$
$$\leq72(-32a^2+4(3-a)a+(3-a)^2)=72(9+6a-35a^2)\leq0$$ because $a\geq1$.

Id est, $f$ decreases and it's enough to prove $f(x)\geq0$ for a maximal value of $bc$, which happens for $b=c$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$64a^4-640a^3b+2112a^2b^2-2560ab^3+1024b^4\geq0$$ or
$$64(a-b)^2(a-4b)^2\geq0$$ and we are done!

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Using calculus, there is a relatively simple solution and the results are more general. When $a,b,c \ge 0$, $a+b+c \ge 0$ and $3(a+b+c)^2 \ge 3(a^2+b^2+c^2) \ge (a+b+c)^2$. We look for minimum and maximum of LHS under the constraints $\{a+b+c=3p,\ a^2+b^2+c^2=3p^2+6r^2\}$, with $p \ge r \ge 0$. Below we allow $a,b,c$ to take negative values too, but the constraints imply that $ab+bc+ca \ge 0$.

Viewing $a, b, c$ as coordinates in 3D Euclidean space, the set of points satisfying the constraints is a circle, which is a closed set without boundary, so both minimum and maximum of LHS must exist and they are at stationary points of the function. Introduce Lagrange multipliers $3m, 3n/2$ for the constraints, take derivatives, the equations of the stationary condition are

$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+p^2}}+m+na=0 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
$$\frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+p^2}}+m+nb=0 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
$$\frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2+p^2}}+m+nc=0 \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

So $a,b,c$ are zeros of the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+p^2}}+m+nx$. Assume $a \le b \le c$. We prove that $a,b,c$ cannot be all distinct. If they are, the first derivative of $f(x)$ must have at least one zero in each of $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$, and the second derivative must have a zero in $(a,c)$. Since $f''(x)=-3p^2x(x^2+p^2)^{-5/2}$ only has one zero at $x=0$, we must have $a<0<c$. Combined with $a+b+c\ge0$ and $ab+bc+ca \ge 0$, we must have $b>0, (a+c)>0$.  $\eqref{eq2}c - \eqref{eq3}b => m<0$, and $\eqref{eq1}c-\eqref{eq3}a => \sqrt{a^2+p^2}>\sqrt{c^2+p^2} => |a|>|c|$. But this contradicts with $a+c>0$.

Given symmetry between $a,b,c$, we can assume $b=c$. Together with the two constraints, $a,b,c$ for the stationary points can be solved: $a=p \pm 2r, b=c=p \mp r$, and
$$
LHS=3(\sqrt{(p \pm 2r)^2+p^2} + 2\sqrt{(p \mp r)^2+p^2}\ )
$$
Plugging in a value like $r=p$ shows that the top sign corresponds to minimum and the bottom sign corresponds to maximum. The minimum is a tighter bound than RHS. To see that, apply Minkowski:
$$
3(\sqrt{(p+2r)^2+p^2} + \sqrt{(2p)^2 + (2p-2r)^2}\ ) \ge 3(\sqrt{(3p+2r)^2+(3p-2r)^2}\ )=3(\sqrt{18p^2+8r^2}\ )=RHS
$$